# How to find my dropdown div if exceeds out of visible screen?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a custom combobox dropdown using angular 4 in my web application.

I have used this custom combobox as one of the field in to list of line items using divs.

Here, I wanna open dropdown in last line item of list, but it exceeds the window screen.
How to make the full dropdown visible to user automatically while opening combobox at the bottom of the page?

```
<div style="height: 56px; margin-left: 7px; min-width:220px" [style.width]="columnsHeaderWidth.division">
    <div style="width:180px; height: 56px; max-width:180px; cursor: pointer;">
        <combo-box [id]="'division-'+user.uuid" [userOption]="true" [isSelected]="false"
        [magicLabelHack]="'projectTypeLabel'"
        [includeMagicLabel]="false"
        bind-placeHolder="'Select division/group...'"
        icon="wizard:chevrondown"
        [source]="divisions" [selectedValue]="user.divisionId" (onSelected)="onChangeDivision($event,user,user.division.id)"
        [isIconItemList]="true" [itemListWidth]="'230px'"
        [changeStyle]="true"
        (click)="rowClick(user)" (onFocusVisible)="tabFocus($event, user)">
        </combo-box>
    </div>
</div>
```

Snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a template variable with some vanilla JS calculation :

```
<div #div style="left: 500px;"></div>

<p *ngIf="div?.getBoundingClientRect().x + div?.getBoundingClientRect().width > totalWidth">
  The div is out of bounds
</p>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3dzpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (change the `style.left` of the div to see it work)

Answer (score 0):

English is just enough broken so I can't decipher what is it that you exactly want, so I assumed that you wanna scroll to the bottom of that dropdown?

In the screenshot you posted I can see the page scroll bar being near the top, I presume that dropdown stretched the page vertically so the end of it is actually visible.

Under those two assumptions, the simplest vanilla solution is to target the last option in dropdown and scroll to it.

`el.scrollIntoView()` is a vanilla solution where el is the DOM element you are after.

Description of options available in the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

if you have it in Angular4, you can get the DOM element via `var el = ang4ele.nativeElement`

It is hard to test this to make it bulletproof for your case before posting due to your code being incomplete (showing only the template part).